# Show that the roots of $x^2+bx+ac=0$ are $a$ times the roots of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ by using transformation of the function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose that roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ are real. Show that the roots of $x^2+bx+ac=0$ are $a$ times the roots of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c=0$ by using an appropriate transformation of the function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=x^2+bx+ac$.

The graph of $y=g(ax)$ results from shifting the graph of $y=g(x)$ horizontally b a factor of $1/a$.

Does that mean $g(ax)=f(x)$?
I'm struggling with realating $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have$$af(x)=a^2x^2+abx+ac=(ax)^2+b(ax)+ac=g(ax)$$indeed. So, $f(x)=0\iff g(ax)=0$ (assuming that $a\ne0$).